# whilst trying to set up stripe payment, I get the error cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm still trying to add a one time stripe payment, but can't figure out the issue, I did some debugging and read threads of others who got a similar error, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Here is my server.js and script.js, note that the variables used in this code is stored in an .env file.

server.js

```
 require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const app = express()
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"))

const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY)

const storeItems = new Map([
    [1,{PriceInCents:1000, name:"Learn React Today"}],
    [2,{PriceInCents:2000, name:"Learn js today"}],
]);


app.post("/create-checkout-session", async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        const session = await stripe.checkout.session.create({
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            mode:"payment",
            line_items:req.body.items.map(item=>{
                const storeItem = sotreItems.get(item.id)
                return{
                    price_data:{
                        currency:"usd",
                        product_data:{
                            name:storeItem.name
                        },
                        unit_amount:storeItem.PriceInCents,
                    },
                    quantity:item.quantity
                }
            }),
            success_url:`${process.env.SERVER_URL}/success.html`,
            cancel_url:`${process.env.SERVER_URL}/cancel.html`
        });        
        res.json({url:session.url})
    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({error:e.message})
    }
})
app.listen(3000)
```

script.js:

```
var submit = document.getElementById("submit")

submit.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    fetch("/create-checkout-session",{
        method:"POST",
        header:{
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            items:[
                {id:1,quantity:1},
            ]
        })
    }).then(res =>{
        if(res.ok) return res.json();
        return res.json().then(json => Promise.reject(json))
        return console.log("url")
    }).then(({url}) =>{
        console.log("url",url)
        // window.location = url
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log("error:", e)
    })
})
```

Comment: Did you successfully run `npm install stripe`? What does your `package.json` look like? Have you logged out your `process.env.STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY` on that page to ensure you are retrieving your secret key successfully?

Comment: you may have a typo, in the docs it's `stripe.checkout.sessions.create` (`sessions` instead of `session`) https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create